# What is the Norse equivalent to the Great Flood?

Tags: norse, myth-identification, comparative, mythohistory, flood-myth

I have constantly heard that every mythology has its own version to explain why the ocean rose after the last ice age ended(roughly 10,000 years ago). But, I have only heard the christian version with Noah, and the Greek version.

Comment: Also, you anyone thinks of any other Great Flood story not from Greek, Norse or Christianity, feel free to mention it.

Comment: Atrahasis and Utanapishtim are two Near Eastern versions, almost identical to each other, and broadly similar to Noah. There is a theory the Near Eastern flood myths developed from an ancient memory of a huge flooding of the Black Sea region.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Norse flood myth is actually a flood of blood, created when Odin, [Vili and Vé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vili_and_V%C3%A9) slew [Ymir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ymir), the primeval ancestor of the [jötnar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6tunn). From Snorri's [*Prose Edda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda):

> The sons of Bor slew the giant Ymer, but when he fell, there flowed so much blood from his wounds that they drowned therein the whole race of frost-giants; excepting one, who escaped with his household. Him the giants call Bergelmer. He and his wife went on board his ark and saved themselves in it.

The resemblance to the biblical flood myth is apparent, apart from Norse Noah being a frost giant and the whole blood thing. Though Norse mythology also says that the world is fashioned from Ymir's body, with his blood being used to create the oceans.

Answer (score 6):

Well though I see the question has been answered. You have asked for other versions of the myth as well. This story originated in Hindu mythology, It is called 'The myth of Manu'. The Hindi word for man - "Manushya" actually traces its roots to this name. He is purported to be the progenitor of all humans according to the Vedas. So in a way it's a way a combination of the myth of Adam and the myth of Noah. I would try to condense the story here but it is pretty long. I can provide a few links though, you can search for the 'The myth of manu' or 'The myth of Matsya Avatar'.

http://hindumythologyforgennext.blogspot.in/2011/11/matsya-avatar.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsya

this one has a more concise version of the myth -

http://www.mythencyclopedia.com/Le-Me/Manu.html

Comment: Welcome to Mythology!  Thanks for contributing.